# Acceder mediante jquery al tercer elemento de un div cargado dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un select que genero dinamicamente y que quiero conseguir el valor de la tercera columna que tiene el select.

```
$('#camion').append("<option value= " + objJsonCamion[i].id + " >" + " " + objJsonCamion[i].mat + "--"+ objJsonCamion[i].name + "--"+objJsonCamion[i].huecos+"</option>");
```

Si yo hago un `alert($("#camion").val());` Me dal el contenido de `objJsonCamion[i].id` y yo el que quiero conseguir es `objJsonCamion[i].huecos`

He intentado Esto `var tercerElementoTexto = $('#camion option:eq(4)').text();`Y me devuelve  mat,name y huecos. Necesito poder identificar de alguna forma en el select cada opción para poder acceder despues a ella. De esta forma solo accedo al valor o a todo lo demás Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Y si le haces un `split()` y obtienes el tercer elemento? algo así `var tercerElementoTexto = $('#camion option:eq(4)').text().split('--')[2];`

Comment: @Cris223511.dev, creo que debería ser `$("#camion option:selected").text().split('--')[2]`

Comment: Pregunto: ¿tú necesitas esto en la vista `objJsonCamion[i].huecos`? Si no lo necesitaras, una opción interesante sería poner ese dato en un [atributo `data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Comment: Muchas Gracias a todos. La respuesta de Marcos me ha funcionado bien, las otras no se si funcionan o no. SI te parece Marcos, pon una respuesta con el comentario para que lo puntue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el valor que estas buscando podes hacerlo así:

```javascript
$("#camion option:selected").text().split('--')[2]
```

Donde:

- Con el selector `#camion option:selected` obtenemos el `<option>` seleccionado en el `<select>`.
- Con `.text()` obtenemos el texto dentro del `<option>`.
- Con `.split('--')` separamos la cadena de texto en un arreglo de `3` posiciones.
- Finalmente con `[2]` obtenemos el valor equivalente a `camion.huecos`.